# Permission error when cloning a git repo

Tags: git, terminal-ide

When I enter `git clone https://207.97.227.239/reponame/repo.git` in terminal-ide, I get this error message:

```
fatal: cannot exec 'git-remote-https': permission denied
```

What will be the possible reason for this?

Comment: do you have access to that repository ?

Comment: i don't know whether i do or not

Comment: THat `cannot exec … permission denied` bit actually means that the web server tried to execute the `git-remote-https` backend (that's "the thing" which serves the remote Git repository), and failed — literally due to insufficient permissions. From the looks of the error message I'd say the remote system is some Unix-y thing (like Linux). Iesnes, please contact your admins as this appears to be a configuration problem, to me.

Comment: @kostix and how do i do that?

Comment: Contact your system administrator? I really do not know: different enterprises have different rules for this. I, for one, usually walk several meters to across a corridor to reach for the office where my IT department is located. YMMV.

Comment: see i am a newbie in this kind of stuff so i still dont get you

Comment: I'm sorry: I have actually misunderstood your question (having been lured by the bare IP address and the ubiquitousness by such "permission denied" errors on servers). In fact the `git-remote-https` is what your local Git calls to establish a Git protocol exchange over HTTPS. On my system (Debian Stretch), that file is `/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https` which is a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-http`, and that one has the access mode set to `0755` (`-rwxr-xr-x`) — that is, execute permissions is granted to everyone.

Comment: So I'd say you should 1) figure out where is the target binary which would called by Git when it executes `git-remote-https` is located; 2) what are the permission bits (and owner / group) are. Please note that this binary is specific to Git so the directory it is installed in typically won't be listed in your $PATH. So if you have installed Git using a package manager of your OS, use its facilities to list the locations of the files it has installed from that Git package. Otherwise I have not much to suggest as we have zero knowledge about your environment.

Comment: i'm actually using Terminal IDE on android as a non-root user